# Regular expression with re.sub does not behave like expected

Tags: python, regex

I'm using re.sub to match and replace everything that is not a number (positive or negative).
So for instance:
i want "-1" to stay "-1" but

- "1" to stay "1"
- -1$" to become "-1"
- "a" to become ""

I have tried with:

```
re.sub('^(-?\d)', "", "-1") 
re.sub('^(-?\d)', "", "1")
```

But it behave the opposite way, not taking into account the ^ negation

Comment: `^` works as negation only inside brackets, as it is it means must start

Comment: woops. My bad forgot the braquet. Thanks @DanielMesejo

Comment: `re.sub('[^-\d]+', "", "-1")`